# reading file returns java.util.NoSuchElementException error

Tags: java, file

Ok, so as part of a challenge I'm writing a program in java to estimate the average amount of bottle caps you'd have to open to win a prize if 1 out of 5 caps has a prize. As part of the challenge, I must write the trial data to a file and read it back to calculate the average. The first part was easy, but I cannot for the life of me figure out why it refuses to read the file back. Every time I attempt to read the file it throws a no such element exception. I hate to be the guy who's just like "HEY, WHATS WRONG WITH MY CODE?" but I don't really have anywhere else to ask and this is really starting to aggravate me. Here is the code:

```
package calculations;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class BottleCapPrize {
static int randomRange (int min, int max){

    int range = (max - min)+1;
    return (int)(Math.random() * range) + min;
    //simple bit of code to return a random number between min and max, inclusively.
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    File text = new File("cap.txt");

    PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter(text);

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Please enter the number of trials: ");
    int trials = in.nextInt();
    boolean won = false;
    int numberoftries = 1;
    int caps;
    while(trials>0){

            while(won==false){
                caps = randomRange(1,5);

                if(caps == 1){
                        won = true;
                    }else{
                        numberoftries +=1;
                }
            }
        won = false;
        outFile.println(numberoftries);
        trials-=1;
        numberoftries=1;
    }

    int total=0;


    Scanner infile = new Scanner(text);

    System.out.println(infile.next());

    while(infile.hasNextInt()){

        total += infile.nextInt();
        System.out.println(total);

    }

    System.out.println((double)total/(double)trials);

    outFile.close();
    infile.close();

}

}
```

Thanks for your help.

Edit: my apologies for not including this earlier

```
Please enter the number of trials: 5
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
at calculations.BottleCapPrize.main(BottleCapPrize.java:51)
```

The problem seems to be with this line "System.out.println(infile.next());"

I also forgot to mention that it writes to the file correctly.

Comment: Add a try/catch + printstacktrace to your code so that you know at which line it happens

Comment: or at least post the stacktrace you have and where the error is occurring...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closing many `Writer` streams, including `PrintWriter`, causes the operation that actually writes to the file.  You currently open an (I'd assume) empty file and then read it before finishing the write operation (aka, before the file has been updated with the new text).

Answer (score 1):

I seem to have found the answer just by messing arround. I have no idea how or why this affects it, but i moved the line "outFile.Close();" to just above the declarations of "int total = 0" (near the bottom.) My best guess is that you cannot reference an edited file without closing it first. thankyou for your help.

Comment: Feel free to comment or answer how this actually affects the code.

Comment: You can't read and write to the same file at the same time so, you get this error.